# Django и ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

Имеется код в **приложении №1** в *models.py*

```py
class Class(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField('Класс', max_length=5)
    pupils = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name='Ученики')
```

В **приложении №2** в *views.py* требуется вывести **department** пользователя, который запросил операцию

```py
def index(request):
    userClass = ???
    return render(request, 'registration/account.html', {'userClass': userClass})
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте `user = request.user`

Answer (score 0):

Импортируете в приложение номер два сам `Class`, в функции `index` определяете входной параметр для `primary_key` и по нему забираете значение объекта

```py
from courses.models import Class

def index(request, pk)
    userClass = Class.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'registration/account.html', {'userClass': userClass})
```

**UPD**

ТСу на заметку:

Переименнуйте все. Класс не должен называться `Class`, метод `index` зарезервирован в python и такой нейминг может вызвать проблемы в дальнейшем

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку на первую строку

Comment: RuntimeError: Model class courses.models.Class doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: приложение называется courses и собственно app1 -> courses

Comment: В первой строке вам надо прописать свой импорт. Я этот взял из головы, поскольку структуры проекта в вопросе нет. Я предположил, что у вас есть приложение `app1`, в котором лежат модели. И _предположительно_ импортировал оттуда

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/F7muxey

Comment: структура проекта

Comment: в auth лежит views.py, а в courses models.py

Comment: Я изменил, я вас прошу, уделите время python'у побольше. Импорт библиотек и модулей - это одна из основополагающих концепций. Потратье час и вы перестанете тут ошибаться

Comment: у меня была написана точно такая же строка и ошибка все ещё остается

Comment: Отлично, читайте ошибку и документации к django